# Which font Github uses for its code viewer?

Tags: github, fonts

Do you know which font github uses for its code viewer? I used several web tools to identify the font but no success.

This is the font:

[image: This is the font]

Comment: Liberation Mono

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

According to the stylesheet, the code is displayed in the first font available on your system:

1. Consolas (on Windows),
2. Liberation Mono,
3. Courier,
4. monospace

It depends on the fonts you have installed on your computer. For Mac OS X 10.9 it defaults to Courier.

Of course, they may at any point change the font to their liking. E.g. to Comic Sans.

Comment: Currently it's `SFMono-Regular, Consolas, Liberation Mono, Menlo, monospace;`

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome's devtools:

```
font-family: ui-monospace,SFMono-Regular,SF Mono,Menlo,Consolas,Liberation Mono,monospace;
```

So, under ideal circumstances, it depends on your browser's settings.